# Sync application data between iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, synchronization, icloud

There are applications that work on both iOS and Android (both Phone and Tablet), and they manage to sync the data across different devices.

1. Are there any frameworks or libraries that provide this sync functionality?
2. If not, what are the different options for implementation?
3. Can iCloud be used for syncing application data across Android and iOS devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any frameworks or libraries that provide this sync functionality?

No. There are no frameworks or libraries that provide the kind of cross-platform sync that iCloud provides for Apple devices.

> If not, what are the different options for implementation?

1. Don't use the sync mechanism at all, and use web-services instead. This might be a good solution for some cases.
2. Use SQLite database in iOS and Android applications, and implement a sync solution on your own. Some of the challenges that you'll face if you choose to implement a custom sync solution are following:

   - Provide a registration mechanism, to use the cloud/server side services
   - Reading and writing data to/from the server/cloud
   - Detecting and resolving conflicts (i.e. merge conflicts)
   - Offline access to the data, and handling situations when device is not connected to any network
   - In iOS, you won't be able to use Core-Data (that makes development relatively very easy), so you'll have to take care of displaying data efficiently, optimizing the data access, etc

> Can iCloud be used for syncing application data across Android and iOS devices?

No. iCloud is only for Apple devices (as of now, July 2012).

Comment: Misleading/Outdated info. Look at other answers.

Answer (score 4):

**Are there any frameworks or libraries that provide this sync functionality?**

You can check out OpenMobster Cloud Platform. The Sync service does secure replication of data between Android and iOS devices. All you have to do is develop the Java Sync Channel on the Cloud Side and use the Device API on the device side to access your data. Here is a link to the project: http://openmobster.googlecode.com

Full Disclosure: I am the Chief Engineer of the OpenMobster platform

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out when I get a chance.

Comment: Can I use OpenMobster for data sync between Android and iOS and Java Desktop or Web App too? If I can, how scalable is this solution? How many users can use it simultaneously? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about iOS, but with Android you can sync data to/from the cloud (your server) with a sync adapter. Example:

http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/index.html

So if you get some data from the iPhone app to your server , you can just sync it to the Android app as well and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox Datastore API can sync your structure data (database), and Sync API and sync images, documents and other files.

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync

They have iOS and Android versions.

Comment: Does dropbox API v2 have callbacks for Android and iOS and desktop applications when the data on Dropbox changes?

Answer (score 0):

EnduroSync from [Orando Labs](https://orandolabs.com) is a new product that does exactly what you are asking. There are clients for iOS and Android, with more coming.

Full Disclosure: I work at Orando Labs.

The EnduroSync clients allow you to create object data stores on the local devices. The clients are fairly sophisticated - data is modeled as native objects for each client we support (iOS and Android now, more coming). The clients work offline and online. The data is saved to an sqlite database locally.

As you change objects in your model, the deltas are recorded on the device. At some point, you can 'sync' the object data store. Syncing uses a commit/push/pull process (like git), but this is invisible to you. The sync brings your local copy up to date with whatever is on the server, and sends up any changes you have made. Conflicts are resolved using a timestamp based merge, so newer data is not overwritten by older data.

EnduroSync is an online service, so there is no server setup on your end.

There is also a flexible permission system which lets you share the object data stores in a variety of ways. For instance, most applications will have one or more object data stores for each user, for preferences, notes, tags, etc. You can also share object data stores per app, per user type, and with wild cards, many other ways.

So basically you use our client SDK's to model your data on the device. Modeling is with simple objects in the native programming language of the device. If you sign
up for the syncing service, you get the syncing also.

Comment: Can you provide a bit of technical background? This way, it's not a simple link to an external resource. Answers should be able to stand on their own; please, check [answer].

Answer (score -1):

the c2dm has been deprecated:

> Important: C2DM has been officially deprecated as of June 26, 2012. This means that C2DM has stopped accepting new users and quota requests. No new features will be added to C2DM. However, apps using C2DM will continue to work. Existing C2DM developers are encouraged to migrate to the new version of C2DM, called Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM). See the C2DM-to-GCM Migration document for more information. Developers must use GCM for new development.

Use the GCM: [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html)